# Qt wheelEvent over all

Tags: qt, scroll, mouseevent

I have app window with many layouts and widget. I have also scrollarea with switch-off scrollbars. I am able to create slots for scrollareaup and scrollareadown. But when I create wheelEvent for all App it's working only for items int app NOT in scrollarea. When I just try this:

```
void TContic_win::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event) {
  cout << "-" << endl;
}
```

I don't know how I can fix it. My idea is something like:

```
bool TContic_win::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e) {

  if (isChildOfScrollWidget(obj) { if (e == wheel) scroll Up or Down }

}
```

Comment: I read your question several times but can't fully understand it. Do you only want to *hide* the scrollbars, but still be able to *scroll* the scrollarea with the mouse wheel?

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this (in case if your widgets have `Your_Scrol_Widget` as parent):

```
void TContic_win::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *we)
{
    if (this->childAt( we->pos() )->parent() == Your_Scrol_Widget)
        qDebug() << "-" ;
}
```

You must got an idea.

Comment: It's not working because when I have scrollbar in mainwindow and I use wheelEvent in mainwindow class. This event is catch everywhere except over scrollarea.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry. It's my mistake. I had a wrong event filter. I used 'return true' in bad conditions so due to this mistake I was always ignore other events and my event filter doesn't work over child items. By the way, thanks for your effort.